# Log4net UDP appender stops sending when UDP listener client disconnected

Tags: c#, udp, log4net

We are using the log4net UDP appender in a Window's service running .NET F/W 4.8.  We use logview4net as a client to watch the messages running on our local workstations.  When we shut/log off at the end of the day and then restart the next morning the UDP appender won't reconnect.   Doing a `netstat -a` shows that the service is not sending anything out on that port.  If we want to reactivate UDP logging we have to restart it.

Is there a way to tell log4net either via code or a setting in the xml config file to start pushing data out for the UDP appender?  Maybe it is something in the [underlying UDP class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: Check task manager to see if application is still running.

Comment: The application is a windows service and it is responding to requests so we know it's running.  Logging works via the RollingFileAppender, just not UDP after client system restart. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have the config files set in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file with `Watch = true`.  Turns out if you use the `touch` command (linux command which changes the file date to today) on the config file it causes log4net to reload the file and it starts pushing UDP again.

Comment: You said the application is running.  I don't think this is a UDP issue.  The application is hanging in trying to access the log file. So I be you are either using a timer or checking date and when you go past midnight the program hangs.